# disable ecommerce

Tags: websites

I have a magento shop with several websites.

I would like to add a website for the technical support only and I want to disable the ecommerce function in that website only.

So far I found only solution where they recommend to disable core module which I can obviously not do as I have other websites.

Any solution on a website base?

Comment: ...so you mean you want to disable the frontend functionality that customers cannot order from the shop, but admins can work on that shop in the backend, right?

Comment: You could try disabling the e-commerce functionality within the template for this store. I.e removing the add to cart, wishlist functionality from the phtml files

Comment: @Anna : no, I want to have a website that present the full catalog but that has just products information.

Comment: One way would be to create a separate theme for this website and write a simple module which would redirect to 404 in specific website/store when the places you don't want would be accessed. I think this would be the easiest and most reliable. Problem gets bigger if you use store switcher's, etc. because the amount of things to extend could grow, and grow.

Answer (score -1):

For this, you have to disable all the backend functionality form where the user cannot order anything from that store like add to cart etc.